# Find subgroups for group of symmetries

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing, permutations, finite-groups

Let A be the group of symmetries of an equilateral triangle.
$A = \{ \varepsilon, \rho, \rho^2, \mu, \mu\rho, \mu\rho^2 \}$,
where $\rho$ is a rotation by $120^\circ$ and $\mu$ holds one corner fixed and swaps the other two. Find all subgroups of $A$. Draw the lattice of subgroups of $A$.

Here's what I'm thinking so far:

So $A$ is defined by the set of operations $\rho$ and $\mu$ and their compositions. So each operation is a permutation? Now I need to find subgroups of $A$. We define a
subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ to be a subset $H$ of $G$ such that when the group operation of
$G$ is restricted to $H$, $H$ is a group in its own right.

So, $A$ has a trivial subgroup, $B = \{\varepsilon\}$.
Other subgroups must follow the rules below:

1. The identity $e$ of $G$ is in $H$. (identity element)
2. If $h_1, h_2 \in H$, then $h_1h_2 \in H$. (closure)
3. If $h \in H$, then $h^{−1} \in H$. (inverse)

That's what I have so far, and I'm having a hard time finding all the subgroups of $A$. How do I know how many there are in total and how do I know I'm not missing any?

Comment: Do you know the Sylow theorems?  That tells you how many possible subgroups of order $2$ and of order $3$ there can be.  Since those are the only possible sizes of non-trivial proper subgroups, that should get you off to a very good start.

Comment: Note: use `\rho`, `\mu`, `\varepsilon`, `\in`, etc. for $\rho, \mu, \varepsilon \in G$

Comment: Your group is finite, so closure requirement suffices for your survey.

Answer (score 2):

There is the trivial subgroup $\{1\}$.

Let subgroup $H$ be nontrivial. If it contains $\rho$ or $\rho^2$, then it contains the subgroup $\{1,\rho,\rho^2\}$. That is another subgroup.

If it contains any of $a\in\{\mu,\mu\rho,\mu\rho^2\}$ then it contains the subgroup $\{1,a\}$, this gives three more subgroups.

If $H$ contains two of the elements from $\{\mu,\mu\rho,\mu\rho^2\}$, then it also contains $\rho$ or $\rho^2$.

Finally if $H$ contains an $a\in \{\mu,\mu\rho,\mu\rho^2\}$ and $\rho$ or $\rho^2$, then it contains all six elements which is easily seen.  That is the last subgroup (the whole group).

There are total of $6$ subgroups.

Comment: How do you know there is only 6 subgroups? Is there a rule or theorem on that?

Comment: @eddie: I have listed all the subgroups.

Comment: sorry, I meant just in general, is there some way to tell how many subgroups a group has based on its elements or size or something like that? Also to draw a lattice of subgroups, I just need to connect all the subgroups: {$1$}, {$1, \rho, \rho^2$}, {$1,a$}, {$\rho, \rho^2$}, {$\mu, \mu\rho, \mu\rho^2$}, {$\mu, \mu\rho, \mu\rho^2,a,\rho,\rho^2$}

Comment: There are no general theorems. The sets $\{\rho,\rho^2\}$ and $\{\mu, \mu\rho,\mu\rho^2\}$ are not subgroups  but $\{1\}$ is. Yes, you need to connect points which denote subgroups.

Comment: Sorry, which ones are the subgroups? I'm a bit confused over what the 6 are? There's these four {$1$}, {$1,ρ,ρ^2$}, {$1,a$}, {$μ,μρ,μρ2,a,ρ,ρ2$}, and the other two?

Comment: There are three subgroups of the form  $\{1,a\}$, every subgroup contains $1$. All of them are listed in the answer.